# Understanding the initial concept of matrix

Tags: matrices

Here is a photo of a page from my math book introducing the concept of matrix:

[image]

With all due respect toward the authors of my math textbook, I can hardly understand the usefulness of matrix from this example.

I mean, if I were an algebra teacher and I had to describe that exam to my students, I would probably come up with something like this on the whiteboard:

```
                        Total Number:      Points available:

Two-point questions:         15                 15x2 = 30
Five-point questions:         4                  4X5 = 20


Total available points from the test: 30 + 20 = 50
```

This way looks much clearer and more practical to me.

And why on earth would I need to write something like this?:

[image]

This wouldn't bring any clarity. I know that the first question that I would ask my teacher then, if I were a student in that class, would be, "What do all those zeroes mean?"

So, how is a matrix useful or practical?

I don't see any practicality in this particular example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you’ve experienced a typical thing in teaching, which is completely useless examples.

Basically any system of linear equations (i.e. a system of equations like $a_1x_1 + \ldots + a_n x_n = b$) can be represented by a matrix. You can think of this as a representation of the system of equations that contains only the nescessary information about the system. Because you do not actually need the variable names, you do not need the $+$ operations. You only need the coefficients $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. In a system of equations you have multiple such lines of coefficients (one for each equation), and that is what a matrix is.
(More correctly a matrix specifies a so called *linear map* from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ where $n$ would be the number of variables and $m$ the number of equations.)

Now in this example we are given a special matrix, which is the identity matrix, that is the matrix that turns $x$ into $x$. So the equation
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}15\\4\end{pmatrix}$$
is really just an unnescessarily complicated way of saying $x=15,y=4$.

Matrices become actually useful when you want to solve such systems of linear equations (also they allow some other useful operations).

If you were to solve $1x+1y=19$, $2x+5y=50$ you’d simply say from the first equation $x=19-y$, and thus $50=2(19-y)+5y =38+3y$. Thus $3y=12$ and thus $y=4$, so $x=19-4=15$. This is a rather messy way way of doing this, especially if the system is really big.

But matrices allow us to do this systematically and fast (in a way that this can be easily performed by a computer). You begin by taking
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 1 & 19 \\ 2 &5 &50\end{array}\right)$$
Now if multiply some line by a number (not $0$) or you subtract a multiple of one line from another line, you do not actually change the solutions. So you want to transform this by this means so that the matrix becomes the unit matrix, then the right part is the solution: Thus we get
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 1 & 19 \\ 0 &3 &12\end{array}\right)$$
then
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 1 & 19 \\ 0 &1 &4\end{array}\right)$$
then
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 0 & 15 \\ 0 &1 &4\end{array}\right)$$
(so we first subtract the first line times $2$ from the second line. Then we divide the second line by $3$ and subtract it from the first line). So we know the solution is $(x,y)=(15,4)$. This method does in fact also tell us if the system is not solvable, and when there are multiple solutions it tells us how they look like. So it is quite a powerful tool.

Comment: WOW! Very clear explanation. Thank you!